# TOAD Editor - View Editor and DBMS Output Side-By-Side

Tags: toad

Is there a way to view an editor and a dbms output window side-by-side so I don't have to tab back and forth between windows in TOAD for Oracle 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to view DBMS Output in Toad. The Editor has a DBMS Output docked panel. You can right click in the Editor and check DBMS Output beneath the Desktop menu flyout. That will show it in the Editor. If you want to see the standalone (MDI) DBMS Output window then open it from the main Toad View menu and your Editor. Then, on the main Toad Window menu choose Tile Vertical. That will align them side by side.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, you can right click the lower title bar, select show dbms output, and then drag the bottom box to the right of the screen.